# How to launch this Xiaomi Font Settings activity?

Tags: adb, xiaomi

I am trying to lauch this activity. But, can't launch.

I've tried like this.

```
adb shell "am start -a com.android.settings -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.Settings$FontSettingsActivity"
```

Anything else I need to try?

[image: Font settings activity]

Answer (score 0):

You can try with monkey commands.

```
monkey -p package_name -v 500
```

An alternative way is to install Nova Launcher. Run it then touch and hold an empty space in the home screen > choose Widget > Activities. Scroll down to the settings icon touch it to expend its activities then touch and hold the one you want to launch.

*And from your command: `adb shell "am start -a com.android.settings -n com.android.settings/com.android.settings.Settings$FontSettingsActivity"` you should just put `/.FontSettingsActivity` after the slash.*

Comment: C:\Users\user>adb shell "am start -a com.android.settings -n com.android.settings/.FontSettingsActivity"
Starting: Intent { act=com.android.settings cmp=com.android.settings/.FontSettingsActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.android.settings/com.android.settings.FontSettingsActivity} does not exist.


The result is like this.

When I tried with monkey it only starts settings.

Comment: Give a try with Nova Launcher